# Pass values into an external js file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cakephp

Hey I hope someone can help me out,

I have an external js file that resides in the webroot/js folder that I insert into my view using:

```
echo $this->Html->script('script');
```

In the js file I have an ajax request to insert data into my database:

```
var assetData = { 
 "project_id":  $("#projectId").val(), 
 "asset_id":"??",
 "content": "content":$(this).html()
};
$.ajax({                    
 url:'/assets/add',
 type:"POST",                                        
 data:assetData
});
```

In my view I created a hidden form field with the project_id so that I can get it in the js file, however the asset items are created dynamically, the are created and saved into the assets table, and now I want to update that asset with the content.

What would be the best way to get the asset? I can't get the id and save it, for example, in the div's id because it was created in the js file.

I would really appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

`/assets/add` should return the ID of the asset it created.

If you're inserting into a mysql database, then one option is to use [`mysql_insert_id`](http://au.php.net/mysql_insert_id) (there are mysqli and pdo equivilents on the manual).

```
var assetData = { 
 "project_id":  $("#projectId").val(), 
 "content": "content":$(this).html()
};
$.ajax({                    
 url:'/assets/add',
 type:"POST",                                        
 data:assetData,
 dataType:'text',
 success:function (data)
 {
    assetData['asset_id'] = (int)data;
 }
});
```

And then your `/assets/add` should echo out the ID after it is created

```
echo $asset_id; // some INT id
```

Comment: hey, i am getting assetData['asset_id'] as undefined. I think I am not returning the value correctly in the controller.I currently have this: public function create($id = null) {
  if ($this->data != null) {
   $this->Asset->save($this->data);
  }
 }

Answer (score 0):

So you may want to consider HTML partials. These are little bits of HTML representing anything from a single tag, to a popup. The important thing is that it does not have the  or  tag.

```
$.post('/assets/add', data, function (html) {
    $('#assets').append(html);
}, 'html');
```

After you POST data, your call returns a snippet of HTML. You can then append that HTML to a DIV on the page.

```
<div id="assets">
   <div class="asset" id="asset-1">
       <p>Asset content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

In your controller (I assume it's CakePHP), you have:

```
if ($this->Asset->save($this->data)) {
    $this->autoLayout = false;
    $this->render('asset_partial.html');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I prefer not to add html if not needed. Seeing that the user can create an unlimited number of assets adding html for each one would not be efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestions I received this is how I managed to solve the problem:

javascript file:

```
$.ajax({                    
    url:'/assets/create',
    type:"POST",                                        
    data:assetData,
    dataType:'text',
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
            alert("response: "+response);
        } else {
            //console.log(response.data, response.code);
            alert("response: "+response);
        }
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
public function create($id = null) {
    if ($this->data != null) {
        $this->Asset->save($this->data);
        $this->autoRender = false;
        echo $this->Asset->id;
    }
}
```